# How to Update APDU Multiple Records

Tags: smartcard, ota, apdu

Is it possible to update multiple records within a single APDU command? For example if I wanted to update PNN with 3 entries, is there a way of sending a single command instead of 3 commands?

Comment: What are PNN records?

Answer (score 0):

No, at least not with an ISO/IEC 7816-4 compatible RECORD based command it seems. Both `UPDATE RECORD` and `APPEND RECORD` only seem to take one record.

If an EF supporting records also supports `UPDATE BINARY` however you may be able to write multiple records directly as bytes. ISO/IEC 7816-4 does seem to leave this option open; then again, 7816-4 leaves a lot of things open.

Of course, if you have a programmable card, anything can be done.

So...it depends.